# Bootstrap col centering

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Building a restaurant menu with bootstrap and I have two columns COL-SM-6 which contain the items of the menu. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to center the two columns but also keep the content aligned left. I've tried offsets and just using margin left but that is messing with the bootstrap responsiveness

```
  <div class="container" id="antipasti">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column">
              <div class="header-text text-center">
                <h3>Antipasti</h3>
                <hr>
              </div>
           </div>[restaurant image][1]
        </div>
        <div class="row" id="items">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>ASPARAGI Grigliati & Fritti<br><span class="info">Ravanello, Aglio & Formaggio di Capra</span></p>
                <p>LOBSTER Caponata<br><span class="info">Artichokes alla Giudia & Coral (~$10pp)</span></p>
                <p>CARNE CRUDA<br> <span class="info">Parmigiano, Zafferano & Croccante di Riso (~$10pp)</span></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <p>VITELLO TONNATO<br><span class="info">Lemon Basil, Capers & Colatura Vinaigrette</span></p>
                <p>Soft Herbs & LETTUCES<br><span class="info">Truffled Dressing</span></p>
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Since bootstrap works with 12 columns, you can't center 2 columns sized with 6. It will use the entire width of the `container`.

Comment: Thanks! yes I had the closing container tag in the wrong spot! DOH! Yea I have tried a few different ways but cant seem to get it right! It looks ok with the text aligned center...May stick with that...thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed the tags properly. The container is closed before row. so, rows are outside of the container.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" id="antipasti">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="header-text text-center">
      <h3>Antipasti</h3>
      <hr>
    </div>
  </div>[restaurant image][1]
  <div class="row" id="items">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>ASPARAGI Grigliati & Fritti<br><span class="info">Ravanello, Aglio & Formaggio di Capra</span></p>
      <p>LOBSTER Caponata<br><span class="info">Artichokes alla Giudia & Coral (~$10pp)</span></p>
      <p>CARNE CRUDA<br> <span class="info">Parmigiano, Zafferano & Croccante di Riso (~$10pp)</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>VITELLO TONNATO<br><span class="info">Lemon Basil, Capers & Colatura Vinaigrette</span></p>
      <p>Soft Herbs & LETTUCES<br><span class="info">Truffled Dressing</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

Per bootstrap's convention, you should use a new `row` and add the `col`,`col-12` for the header.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container" id="antipasti">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
      <div class="header-text text-center">
        <h3>Antipasti</h3>
        <hr>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row" id="items">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>ASPARAGI Grigliati & Fritti<br><span class="info">Ravanello, Aglio & Formaggio di Capra</span></p>
      <p>LOBSTER Caponata<br><span class="info">Artichokes alla Giudia & Coral (~$10pp)</span></p>
      <p>CARNE CRUDA<br> <span class="info">Parmigiano, Zafferano & Croccante di Riso (~$10pp)</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>VITELLO TONNATO<br><span class="info">Lemon Basil, Capers & Colatura Vinaigrette</span></p>
      <p>Soft Herbs & LETTUCES<br><span class="info">Truffled Dressing</span></p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```